# Python convert string to dictionary json

Tags: python

String "output" has below value:

```
interface Vlan364
  ip policy route-map RM_OUT
interface Vlan234
  ip policy route-map RM_OUT
interface Vlan235
  ip policy route-map RM_OUT
interface Ethernet1/2
  ip policy route-map RM_IN
interface Ethernet1/6
  ip policy route-map RM_IN
```

1. How to convert it to a dictionary "outputDict" that would look like the following:

   ```
   {
       "interface":"Vlan364", "ip policy route-map":"RM_OUT",
       "interface":"Vlan234", "ip policy route-map":"RM_OUT",
       "interface":"Vlan235", "ip policy route-map":"RM_OUT",
       "interface":"Ethernet1/2", "ip policy route-map":"RM_IN",
       "interface":"Ethernet1/6", "ip policy route-map":"RM_IN",
   }
   ```

   Goal here is to identify "ip policy route-map" associated with each   "interface".
2. How to find out unique "ip policy route-map" in above dictionary and put it in list. i.e. output from above dictionary would be:

   ```
     route-map_list = [RM_OUT, RM_IN]
   ```

Comment: Can you show us any code that you've already tried? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Python dictionary keys need to be unique, i.e. you can only have one 'interface' and one 'ip policy route-map' inside the 'outputDict', see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more, so you might have to update the desired output before anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match the keywords, and then user `re.finditer` to search for all matches, and put the match objects into a list of dictionaries.

```
import re, json

output = """interface Vlan364
  ip policy route-map RM_OUT
interface Vlan234
  ip policy route-map RM_OUT
interface Vlan235
  ip policy route-map RM_OUT
interface Ethernet1/2
  ip policy route-map RM_IN
interface Ethernet1/6
  ip policy route-map RM_IN"""

output_list = []
route_map_list = []
REGEX_STRING = r"interface ([A-Za-z0-9//]+)[\n\r ]+ip policy route-map ([A-Z_]+)"
for match in re.finditer(REGEX_STRING,output):
    output_list.append(
        {
            "interface": match.group(1),
            "ip policy route-map": match.group(2)
        }
    )
    if match.group(2) not in route_map_list:
        route_map_list.append(match.group(2))

print(json.dumps(output_list, indent=4))
print(route_map_list)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "interface": "Vlan364",
        "ip policy route-map": "RM_OUT"
    },
    {
        "interface": "Vlan234",
        "ip policy route-map": "RM_OUT"
    },
    {
        "interface": "Vlan235",
        "ip policy route-map": "RM_OUT"
    },
    {
        "interface": "Ethernet1/2",
        "ip policy route-map": "RM_IN"
    },
    {
        "interface": "Ethernet1/6",
        "ip policy route-map": "RM_IN"
    }
]
['RM_OUT', 'RM_IN']
```